# Using grep command to find a file in "*.py"

Tags: linux

I'm using Linux grep command to find a word in a list of files but it's not working as expected...

THis is the command Im using

```
$find -iname "*.py" | grep -i django
```

find -iname "*.py"  = gives me all the *.py file but grep does not work on top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep doesn't take filenames to search from stdin. Try instead:

```
find -iname "*.py" | xargs grep -i django
```

or for bonus points (dealing with filenames that have spaces)

```
find -iname "*.py" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i django
```

Comment: Or `find  -name '*.py'  -exec grep -H -i django '{}' ';'`.

Comment: @Cobbal: IT works thanks..Also, on the same lines..I tried grep -r django *.py but that does not work..any thoughts?

Comment: @user1050619 "*.py" is expanded into all python filenames in the current directory before grep even sees it, so the `-r` flag does nothing. Some shells (zsh for sure, and bash I think) will let you do something like `grep django **/*.py` which will expand into all python files in all subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks,,,So, (find -iname "*.py" | xargs grep -i django) should be equal to (grep -ir django **/*.py) , Correct?..but the results are different

Comment: @user1050619 There might be some differences with symlinks, case sensitivity and spaces in file names, but I can't say exactly why your results would be different.